# CSS + flex + height 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing a problem that I'm building a page using GWT framework and I'm trying to set 100% of height to an element and it doesn't work.

Is something like that:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="1">
        <div id="2"> 
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Div main - I don't have access to change the code, because is a framework;

Div 1 - `style=display:flex;`

Div 2 - `style=display:flex;flex-direction:column; height:100%;`

And so on..

Using the chrome developer tools if I set the height 100% for the main div and the div 1, I will get height 100% for my content, otherwise I won't.

The question is, how can I set it without change the main div? Because as I said, I don't have access to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to use the `flex: 1` rule. I think I fully understand that your `#main` has a height that can not be touched, and your most child `<div>` should fill the content. Try the following and check out the example...

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div id="one">
            <div id="two"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    #one {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    #two { 
        flex: 1;
    }
```

Note - I changed your ID's for CSS selectors. Unsure if this is how you were doing it, but keep in mind why [ID’s Cannot Start With a Number](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/) is you intent to target them with CSS selectors.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2v423zpg/) - working example

Comment: Under HTML**5** IDs *can* start with a number {[**SO Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)} but it's still not recommended.

Comment: Sure they can it's just tricky if you want to target them with CSS selectors. There are workarounds in the article for it